# Restrict access to images from browser directly

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-location

I have a web site developed in Angular 8 and Web API developed in .Net Core. I have hosted this web site on Linux VM with Nginx.

My folder structure on the linux server is as below.

**/var/www/mywebsite/angularapp** here is my angular application

**/var/www/mywebsite/dotnetcorewebapi** here is my web api

I have some jpeg images saved in below location.

**/var/www/mywebsite/preprocessedimages**

Here is the question: I want these images to be accessed only thru my web site but not directly from the browser.

which means I want to restrict the user to access the images by typing in below from the browser, however the same image should be able to render in my web application

`https://mywebsite/getprocessedimage/image.jpeg`

What options do I have to achieve this functionality. I believe this is more of a setting on nginx default file. A quick help is greatly appreciated. Below is the nginx default file.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    root /var/www/mywebsite/angularapp;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri /index.html; 
    }
    
    #if the request is for API
    location ~* /coreapi{
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:port;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    #if the request is for image
    location ^~ /getprocessedimage/ {
        #autoindex on;
        alias /var/www/mywebsite/preprocessedimages;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

all images uploaded on a server shall and will be available via it's path. I don't think you can restrict access to unless you use some type of authentication such as username/password to view through an API such as google drive's API, from there the image may come on the backend and then redirected to the frontend. There is no way someone can access the folder like this.[Here documentation for Google Drive's API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk)